# Filling the series in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data which data which looks something like this

/********************************************************************************/
YYMM  Sector
1701  Agriculture
1611 Retail
1501  CRE
/*************/
There is another dataset which looks something like this/*************

Customer_ID  YYMM
XXXX         1702
XXXX         1701
XXXX         1612
XXXX         1611
XXXX         1610
XXXX         1510
XXXX         1509
/********************************************************/

So basically I want to mere these two datasets on the basis of YYMM but and merge in the sectors. But since the previous data has only few YYMM all I want to do is copy the sectors till a new yymm is encountered from the first dataset.
So the sector from 1701 to 1612 should be agriculture and the sector from 1611 to 1502 is retail and for any month before 1501 it has to be CRE.

Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Formats, arrays, SQL join - that all will work. You might want to pre-process the first table so it contains from - to values (e.g. 1502 - 1611 Retail).
If the transformation is done in SAS (not passed to another RDBMS), I think using format is fastest. Join on the other hand is the simple solution. Let me know if you need help with pre-processing of the first table (can be easily done in data step).

Comment: Post what you've tried so far please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with proc format. Since your data is in yymm format you can set the limits logical without the data conversion, but I feel more comfortable with actual dates.

```
data Begin;
    input Customer_ID $ YYMM $;
    cards;
    XXXX 1702
    YYYY 1701
    ZZZZ 1612
    OOOO 1611
    AAAA 1610
    FFFF 1510
    DDDD 1509
; run;

data with_date;
    set begin; 
    date = mdy(substr(yymm,3,2), 1, substr(yymm,1,2) );
run;

proc format;  /*Didn't check the bins too much. Adjust as needed.*/
    value sector
    low - '1jan2015'd ='lows'
    '1jan2015'd < - '1nov2016'd  = 'CRE' 
    '1nov2016'd < - '1jan2017'd  = 'Retail'
    '1jan2017'd < - high  = 'Agriculture'
 ;
run;

data wanted;
    set with_date;
    format date sector.;
run;
```

For more on proc format see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473474.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL based solution (similar to the one proposed by pinegulf).

Let us create test datasets:

```
data T01;
length Sector $20;
infile cards;
input YYMM_to Sector;
cards;
1701 Agriculture
1611 Retail
1501 CRE
;
run;

data T02;
length Customer_id $10;
infile cards;
input Customer_ID YYMM;
cards;
AXXX 1702
BXXX 1701
CXXX 1612
DXXX 1611
EXXX 1610
FXXX 1510
GXXX 1509
;
run;
```

We can add a "YYMM_from" column to T01:

```
proc sort data=T01;
by YYMM_to;
run;

data T01;
set T01;
by YYMM_to;
YYMM_from=lag(YYMM_to);
if _N_=1 then YYMM_from=0;
run;

proc print data=T01;
run;
```

We get:

```
Obs     Sector       YYMM_to     YYMM_from
------------------------------------------
1       CRE          1501        0
2       Retail       1611        1501
3       Agriculture  1701        1611
```

Then comes the join:

```
proc sql;
create table T03 as
select a.*, b.Sector
from T02 a LEFT JOIN T01 b
on YYMM_from<a.YYMM<=YYMM_to;
quit;

proc print data=T03;
quit;
```

We get:

```
Obs    Customer_id   YYMM    Sector
-----------------------------------------
1      DXXX          1611    Retail
2      EXXX          1610    Retail
3      FXXX          1510    Retail
4      GXXX          1509    Retail
5      BXXX          1701    Agriculture
6      CXXX          1612    Agriculture
7      AXXX          1702
```